# How to find the number of groups of 5 with 2 defective modems.

Tags: combinatorics

A store has 80 modems in its inventory, 30 coming from Source A and the
remainder from Source B: Of the modems from Source A; 20% are defective.
Of the modems from Source B; 8% are defective. How many groups of 5
modems will have exactly two defective modems?

so i am not looking for the probability, but instead i am looking for how many groups of 5 will have the defective modems. I know have am going to use combinations but i just don't know how. I know there are 24 non defective modems, 6 defectives ones from A  and 46 non defective modems, 4 defective ones from B.

Comment: choose 3 from total normal units and 2 from total defective units?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, you have a total of $d = 10$ defective and $n = 70$ non-defective modems. You need to combine 2 defective modems with 3 non-defective modems.

Your answer is:
$$
{d \choose 2} \times {n \choose 3} = {10 \choose 2} \times {70 \choose 3} = 45 \times 54,740 = 2,463,300
$$

Comment: Thank you. I made it so much more difficult than it needed to be.